# How do I replace all numbers with a modified version of that number? (Python)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have this object:

```
obj = "1231 qlwdrn,555, ;wlrd wqd 111 qwd,112,"
```

I'd like to add single-quotes around each set of digits that are bracketed by commas.

My desired output

```
obj = "1231 qlwdrn,'555', ;wlrd wqd 111 qwd,'112',"
```

I know how to match the numbers, but I don't know how to keep those same numbers for the replacement. This is where I"m at.

```
import re 

obj = "1231 qlwdrn,555, ;wlrd wqd 111 qwd,112,"

obj.sub(r",\d+,", [what do I put here?])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a capture group around the number, so you can copy it into the replacement.

Also, `sub` is an `re` method, not a string method. You need to pass the string as an argument, and assign the result.

```
obj = re.sub(r",(\d+),", r",'\1',", obj)
```

`\1` is replaced by whatever matched the capture group `(\d+)` number 1.

Comment: Can you explain what the \1 does in this? Is it a stand-in for the numbers?

Comment: @Cauder It's a stand-in for the first capture group (which in this case is the only capture group).

Comment: Is there a way for this to work with overlapping matches? eg `,1,2,`

Comment: You could do it using lookarounds instead of including the commas in the matches.